# Unmarshal dynamic JSON and marshal into struct

Tags: json, go

I send a decrypted message produced from ruby via API

```
rawData = {value: 1}
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('aes-256-gcm')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.iv = iv
cipher.key = key
cipher.auth_data = auth_data
cipherText = cipher.update(JSON.generate(rawData)) + cipher.final
authTag = cipher.auth_tag
hexString = (iv + cipherText + authTag).unpack('H*').first

# result
# "366138323563323565613734cb4ebc43e13176adb7825ddc3806e8fa9abaf39aa32ef210568c08"
```

and want decrypt in golang

```
type ResultPlainText struct {
    Plaintext string `json:"plaintext"`
}

type PermitRequest struct {
    Data string `json:"data"`
}

// request body will be
// { "data": "366138323563323565613734cb4ebc43e13176adb7825ddc3806e8fa9abaf39aa32ef210568c08" }
func requestPlainText(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var permit PermitRequest
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&permit)
    permitData := permit.Data
    encodedStr, _ := hex.DecodeString(permit.Data)
    key := []byte("972ec8dd995743d981417981ac2f30db")
    authData := []byte("73f6828fc5be")

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    aesGcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    sz := aesGcm.NonceSize()
    nonce, cipherText := encodedStr[:sz], encodedStr[sz:]

    rawData, err := aesGcm.Open(nil, nonce, cipherText, authData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var buffData map[string]interface{}
    f := json.Unmarshal(rawData, &buffData)
    if f != nil {
        panic(f.Error())
    }

    plaintext := buffData["value"].String()
    result := ResultPlainText{ Plaintext: plaintext}
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

I want to put directly into the struct type..

Get this error

```
Unresolved reference 'String'
```

Comment: @mkopriva actually, my case is complex, I will edit my thread to explain original case.

Comment: And just to clarify the error, it is clearly coming from the following expression: `buffData["value"].String()`, this is because `buffData` is of type `map[string]interface{}` which means that  the expression `buffData["value"]` evaluates to a value of type `interface{}` which does NOT have a method `String()`, in fact it has NO methods, zero, nada, that's why it's called the empty interface.

Comment: @mkopriva json field will contain dynamic type data, not just a string or an integer. I just want to find another way, in Ruby I can use Marshal dump and Marshal load for that, but it will depend to major version of Ruby, so I try with JSON and need find workaround to handle it in Golang

Comment: What format is plaintext supposed to be in?

Comment: If I'm reading your sample correctly then what you probably want is `type ResultPlainText struct { Plaintext json.RawMessage \`json:"plaintext"\`}` and `map[string]json.RawMessage` and then just use that directly `plaintext := buffData["value"]`. See [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage)

Comment: @mkopriva plaintext supposed to be in string

Comment: Ok, but if, as you say, the value can contain dynamic type data, does that mean it can contain also a complex object? or are you talking only about scalar types? And if it can contain an object, how should that object be represented in plaintext?

Comment: @mkopriva it's works but the plaintext to be in original format, but it's no problem for me since I wanted it..

Comment: @mkopriva I will try with another type data to see that's work.

Comment: @mkopriva could you please write the solution as answer, so I can approve it as a solution for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage) instead of `string` as the plaintext type.

```golang
type ResultPlainText struct {
    Plaintext json.RawMessage `json:"plaintext"`
}

// ...

var buffData map[string]json.RawMessage
f := json.Unmarshal(rawData, &buffData)
if f != nil {
    panic(f.Error())
}

w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
_ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ResultPlainText{
    Plaintext: buffData["value"],
})
```